# Constructing relatively ample line bundles

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let us work over $\mathbb C$.

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety with an ample line bundle $L$. Let $S$ be any scheme over $\mathbb C$, reduced or integral (or... add more assumptions if necessary). For a closed subscheme $$V\subset X\times S,$$ is the projection map $V\to S$ projective? I was thinking to maybe use $L$ to build up a relatively ample line bundle on $V$, as follows: just taking the restriction to $V$ of the line bundle $L\otimes_{\mathbb C}\mathcal O_S$ on $X\times S$. Does this work? What assumptions do I need to know that $$V\subset X\times S\overset{\textrm{pr}}{\to}S$$ is projective? Thanks!

Comment: It seems you know that $X\times S\to S$ is projective. It follows that any closed subscheme of $X\times S$ is also projective over $S$.

Comment: I do not really know, I am always a bit careful about relative issues. So is $X\times S\to S$ projective (for any $S$) because $X$ is? I mean, $L\otimes \mathcal O_S$ seems to be relatively ample...

Comment: I don't understand what we need ample sheaves for in this context. Projective morphisms are stable under base change.

Comment: You are of course right, that was silly.